# Why won't this print out anything?

Tags: clojure

Why won't this print out anything, but it works if i just use (print "ASDAS") ,I'm using LightTable and It's printint out in the console.

```
(defn try [x]
 (print ("ASDASD")
))

(try 5)
```

Comment: If it worked you are trying to call a string as a function in `("ASDASD")`. What result are you expecting from that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`try` is a special form for exception handling. See the [Clojure Documentation](https://www.clojure.org/reference/special_forms#try) for it.

You can either:

- Refer to it directly via `(your-ns-here/try 5)`, likely `(user/try 5)`.
- Use a different name for your function.

Comment: IMO it should either work by shadowing `try` (Scheme does this) or complain about `try` being reserved (most languages does this). Ignoring `#'user/try` is a weakness and source of error.

Comment: @Sylwester It's not as simple as that. `try` doesn't seem to exist in Scheme as a special form, so I'm not sure what comparison you had in mind. But in Clojure, if we allowed shadowing of `try/catch/finally`, what would you do with an ordinary `try` inside a scope where `catch` is shadowed? Most special forms can indeed be shadowed (eg `fn`), but `try/catch/finally` are complicated because they are a threesome that work together.

Comment: @amalloy Scheme has exception handling with different syntax (`guard`). When i do `(catch ...)` outside of `try` I get `catch: undefined` so I guess if `try` was overridden and it has a `catch` inside it would not assume it to be `catch` but another function or macro with that name not defined.

Answer (score 0):

try function in Clojure Is used for exception handling... change your function and see.

[https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/try]

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
("ASDF")
```

is a function call, but a string is not a function.  Doesn't work.

This thus doesn't work either:

```
(print ("ASDF"))
```

In order to print the string:

```
(print "ASDF")
```

The name `try` is not a good idea, because it shadows the already existing name from Clojure core.

So:

```
(defn my-experiment [x]
  (print x))

(my-experiment "ASDF")
```